# How to access view inside activity from adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

Does anyone knows how to access adapter imageView inside activity to hide the view. Please specify any example.

Comment: Adapter of what exactly? RecyclerView?

Comment: Yes, RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

By using `SharedPreferences` we can easily hide the view from activity or fragment.

Save flag in `SharedPreferences` i.e true from activity.

If you are using `Recyclerview` then in `onBindViewHolder` method check condition

```
if(flag==true){
    holder.yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
    holder.yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to onBindViewHolder of the adapter and take the id of your imageview and code like this
holder.mImgVw.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: No, this is a very-very bad idea. The concept of RecyclerView is to display already prepared data. Not to interact with it in means of modifying. If you want to change something about your data, just update the whole dataset and let RecyclerView do it's best (whether you have written your own solution on how to update data or using DiffUtils, or just relaying of `nofityDatasetChanged`). For two-way communications use callbacks

Comment: But as per the question my answer is to the point.I just showed how to hide a view from a adapter. nofityDatasetChanged() is the method to notify the adapter that the data has changed if one change data by edit or delete or anything with a card of recyclerview.Then we have to call the method nofityDatasetChanged().But here as per the question that will be of another topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly interact with the ImageView, instead you can use `notifyItemChanged()` to update the ImageView state in the Adapter. But, you need to slightly modify your Adapter code by adding a flag in your model data or using [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray) as a mechanism to saving the ImageView state.

Here the example:

```
public class Adapter ... {
  private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItems;
  private List<YourModel> mItems;

  public Adapter(List<YourModel> items) {

    mItems = items;
    mSelectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
  }

  ...
  public void onBindViewHolder(....) {
    int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    YourModel item = items.get(itemPosition);

    boolean visible = mSelectedItems.get(itemPosition);   
    viewHolder.imageView.setVisibility(visible? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);

    ...
  }

  public void setItemVisibilityByPosition(int position, boolean visible) {
    mSelectedItems.put(position, visible);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
  }

}
```

You can change the image visibility with:

```
 // Assume the mAdapter is your Adapter
 mAdapter.setItemVisibilityByPosition(5, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @ישו אוהב אותך  , Can you explain little bit more ?  because I think you done with selected position wise.